# Eliminate space before period unless followed by a digit

Tags: regex, r

How can I use R's regex to eliminate space(s) before period(s) unless period is followed by a digit?

Here's what I have and what I've tried:

```
x <- c("I have .32 dollars AKA 32 cents . ", 
    "I have .32 dollars AKA 32 cents .  Hello World .")

gsub("(\\s+)(?=\\.+)", "", x, perl=TRUE)
gsub("(\\s+)(?=\\.+)(?<=[^\\d])", "", x, perl=TRUE)
```

**This gives (no space before `.32`):**

```
## [1] "I have.32 dollars AKA 32 cents. "             
## [2] "I have.32 dollars AKA 32 cents.  Hello World."
```

**I'd like to get:**

```
## [1] "I have .32 dollars AKA 32 cents. "             
## [2] "I have .32 dollars AKA 32 cents.  Hello World."
```

I'm saddled with `gsub` here but other solutions welcomed to make the question more usable to future searchers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a complex expression, you can use a **Positive Lookahead** here.

```
> gsub(' +(?=\\.(?:\\D|$))', '', x, perl=T)
## [1] "I have .32 dollars AKA 32 cents. "             
## [2] "I have .32 dollars AKA 32 cents.  Hello World."
```

**Explanation**:

```
 +        # ' ' (1 or more times)
(?=       # look ahead to see if there is:
  \.      #   '.'
  (?:     #   group, but do not capture:
    \D    #      non-digits (all but 0-9)
   |      #     OR
    $     #      before an optional \n, and the end of the string
  )       #   end of grouping
)         # end of look-ahead
```

**Note:** If these space characters could be any type of whitespace just replace `' '+` with `\s+`

---

If you are content with using the `(*SKIP)(*F)` backtracking verbs, here is the correct representation:

```
> gsub(' \\.\\d(*SKIP)(*F)| +(?=\\.)', '', x, perl=T)
## [1] "I have .32 dollars AKA 32 cents. "             
## [2] "I have .32 dollars AKA 32 cents.  Hello World."
```

Comment: This answer is indeed a more efficient solution and I am marking this as the accepted solution though other provided very usable solutions that may suit other future searcher's needs better. +1

Answer (score 3):

Well, I don't know r, but I know regular expressions. Hopefully this answer works in r.

```
gsub("\\s+\\.(?!\\d)", ".", x, perl=TRUE)
```

It uses a negative lookahead to ensure that the space(s) and period are not followed by a digit; then it replaces the match with just a period.

Comment: +1 This is the solution that I would use and does, most simply what the OP asked. I was about to post exactly this before I actually scrolled down to non-upvoted answers just to check!

Comment: This solution also works well.  For my particular circumstance I would prefer replacing with `""` for others with similar tasks this solution may be ideal.  +1

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for the example.

```
  gsub("\\s(?=\\.[0-9])(*SKIP)(*F)|(\\s+)(?=\\.+)(?<=[^\\d])", "", x, perl=TRUE)
  #[1] "I have .32 dollars AKA 32 cents. "             
  #[2] "I have .32 dollars AKA 32 cents.  Hello World."
```

Comment: Yeah it does, unfortunately,  I think I may have made the MWE too minimal.  I added another line.

Comment: I removed the check as hwnd has a more efficient aprpoach.  Thank you for the solution and learning.  +1

Comment: @Tyler Rinker.  Thanks. I also think hwnd's approach much better than mine.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
x <- c("I have .32 dollars AKA 32 cents . ", 
       "I have .32 dollars AKA 32 cents .  Hello World .",
       "I have .32 dollars AKA 32 cents .  Hello World .xyz")

gsub(" *\\.($|\\D)", "\\.\\1", x)
[1] "I have .32 dollars AKA 32 cents. "                
[2] "I have .32 dollars AKA 32 cents.  Hello World."   
[3] "I have .32 dollars AKA 32 cents.  Hello World.xyz"
```

What it does:

- `" *\\."` searches for a any number of spaces followed by a period.
- `"($|\\D)"` searches for either:

  - the end of the line (`$`),
  - or "not a digit" (`\\D`)

Comment: This also works. +1  For my purposes I liked akrun's solution a bit better (it subs out with `""`).  I can see many others would prefer this solution per their circumstances.